# PEST Parser does not recognise comments

Tags: parsing, rust, pest

I'm trying to write a parser with PEST the Rust parser generator. I'm having trouble with a fairly simple grammar. `file` is the top level rule in the grammar. It contains the `SOI` and `EOI` rules.

```
// example.pest

WHITESPACE = _ { "\n" | " " }
COMMENT = _{ "(*" ~ ANY* ~ "*)" }

KEYWORD = { ^"keyword" }

file = _{ SOI ~ KEYWORD ~ EOI }
```

Here is the contents of the file I'm trying to parse:

```
(*
*)
keyword
```

The generated parser cannot parse this file. The error looks like this:

```
1 | (*␊
  | ^---
  |
  = expected KEYWORD
```

The built in `COMMENT` rule should handle this situation. Is whitespace handled differently inside comments?

How to properly write a grammar with comments?

Comment: What kind of line endings does your test file use? IOW is it a Windows (`\r\n`), Linux (`\n`) or MacOS (`\r`) file?

Comment: It wasn't actually related to line endings. See the answer I posted

Answer (score 3):

There is actually an error in the logic of the grammar as given here. This rule in the grammar will match everything to the end of the file.

```
COMMENT = _{ "(*" ~ ANY* ~ "*)" }
```

The rule should be

```
COMMENT = _{ "(*" ~ (!"*)" ~ ANY)* ~ "*)" }
```

This means that any number of characters will be matched, but not anything that looks like `*)`. Once `*)` is encountered, the next part of the sequence is reached and `*)` is matched and the whole rule is fulfilled.